# REST api within phalcon application like INVO

Tags: rest, api, phalcon

I hope many of you knows about the INVO framework in phalcon.

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-invo.html

This is a very strong framework to built and application very fast.I very like this framework.
I have a little application built of INVO.

And Now I want to implement `REST` within this framework so that I can open my APIs to different users outside the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are many API implementations you can consider with Phalcon.

https://github.com/sergeyklay/awesome-phalcon

This site has a lot of resources (see `RESTful`) that will help you get started.

Also the latest version of the Phalcon website utilizes the `Phalcon\Mvc\Micro` application which is suitable for API development as well as middleware. You might want to check those too:

https://github.com/phalcon/website

https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/building-the-new-phalcon-website-implementation-part-1

https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/building-the-new-phalcon-website-bootstrap-part-2

https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/building-the-new-phalcon-website-middleware-part-3